# VB6 shell process waiting for client before continuing with the main thread

Tags: multithreading, vb6

I want to create an application to start a process like CMD or MySQL Console and input commands to it and read the output without using files.

The code I got from stackoverflow keeps suspending the main thread when I need to use `ReadAllOutput()`, and even after I close the client thread the main thread does not receive output from the client.

I need to keep the client thread active because I need to log on to some systems.

Here is the class I am using:

```
Option Explicit
DefObj A-Z
Private Const MODULE_NAME As String = "cExec"

'=========================================================================
' API
'=========================================================================

'--- for CreateProcess
Private Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW          As Long = 1
Private Const STARTF_USESTDHANDLES          As Long = &H100
Private Const SW_HIDE                       As Long = 0
Private Const SW_MINIMIZE                   As Long = 6
Private Const NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS         As Long = &H20&
'--- for WaitForSingleObject
Private Const INFINITE                      As Long = &HFFFFFFFF
'--- for DuplicateHandle
Private Const DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS         As Long = &H2
'--- for GetExitCodeProcess
Private Const STATUS_PENDING                As Long = &H103

Private Declare Function CreateProcessA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal lpProcessAttributes As Long, ByVal lpThreadAttributes As Long, ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, ByVal lpEnvironment As Long, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As String, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreatePipe Lib "kernel32" (phReadPipe As Long, phWritePipe As Long, lpPipeAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcess Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function DuplicateHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSourceProcessHandle As Long, ByVal hSourceHandle As Long, ByVal hTargetProcessHandle As Long, lpTargetHandle As Long, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwOptions As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long, lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long, ByVal lpOverlapped As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function TerminateProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal uExitCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WriteFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nNumberOfBytesToWrite As Long, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long, ByVal lpOverlapped As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function FlushFileBuffers Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function PeekNamedPipe Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hNamedPipe As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nBufferSize As Long, lpBytesRead As Long, lpTotalBytesAvail As Long, lpBytesLeftThisMessage As Long) As Long

Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb                  As Long
    lpReserved          As String
    lpDesktop           As String
    lpTitle             As String
    dwX                 As Long
    dwY                 As Long
    dwXSize             As Long
    dwYSize             As Long
    dwXCountChars       As Long
    dwYCountChars       As Long
    dwFillAttribute     As Long
    dwFlags             As Long
    wShowWindow         As Integer
    cbReserved2         As Integer
    lpReserved2         As Long
    hStdInput           As Long
    hStdOutput          As Long
    hStdError           As Long
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess            As Long
    hThread             As Long
    dwProcessId         As Long
    dwThreadId          As Long
End Type

Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength             As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
    bInheritHandle      As Long
End Type

'=========================================================================
' Constants and member variables
'=========================================================================

Private m_hProcess          As Long
Private m_hReadOutput       As Long
Private m_hReadError        As Long
Private m_hWriteInput       As Long

'=========================================================================
' Error handling
'=========================================================================

Private Sub PrintError(sFunc As String)
    MsgBox Error & " in " & MODULE_NAME & "." & sFunc & "(" & Erl & ")", vbCritical, App.EXEName
End Sub

'=========================================================================
' Methods
'=========================================================================

Public Function Run( _
            sFile As String, _
            sParams As String, _
            Optional ByVal bStartHidden As Boolean, _
            Optional ByVal bStartMimized As Boolean) As Boolean
    Const FUNC_NAME     As String = "Run"
    Dim uProcInfo       As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim uStart          As STARTUPINFO
    Dim sCommandLine    As String
    Dim uSA             As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    Dim hTmp            As Long
    Dim hWriteOutput    As Long
    Dim hWriteError     As Long
    Dim hReadInput      As Long

    On Error GoTo EH
    '--- cleanup previous
    If m_hProcess <> 0 Then
        Call CloseHandle(m_hProcess)
        m_hProcess = 0
    End If
    If m_hReadOutput <> 0 Then
        Call CloseHandle(m_hReadOutput)
        m_hReadOutput = 0
    End If
    If m_hReadError <> 0 Then
        Call CloseHandle(m_hReadError)
        m_hReadError = 0
    End If
    '--- win9x: fix spaces or not working on 9X
    If InStr(sFile, " ") > 0 And Left$(sFile, 1) <> """" Then
        sCommandLine = """" & sFile & """" & " " & sParams
    Else
        sCommandLine = sFile & " " & sParams
    End If
    '--- create pipes
    uSA.nLength = Len(uSA)
    uSA.bInheritHandle = 1
    Call CreatePipe(hTmp, hWriteOutput, uSA, 0)
    Call DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hTmp, GetCurrentProcess(), m_hReadOutput, 0, False, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
    Call CloseHandle(hTmp)
    Call CreatePipe(hTmp, hWriteError, uSA, 0)
    Call DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hTmp, GetCurrentProcess(), m_hReadError, 0, False, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
    Call CloseHandle(hTmp)
    Call CreatePipe(hReadInput, hTmp, uSA, 0)
    Call DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), hTmp, GetCurrentProcess(), m_hWriteInput, 0, False, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
    Call CloseHandle(hTmp)
    '--- setup start info
    uStart.cb = Len(uStart)
    uStart.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
    uStart.hStdInput = hReadInput  ' GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
    uStart.hStdOutput = hWriteOutput
    uStart.hStdError = hWriteError
    If bStartHidden Then
        uStart.dwFlags = uStart.dwFlags Or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        uStart.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
    End If
    If bStartMimized Then
        uStart.dwFlags = uStart.dwFlags Or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
        uStart.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE
    End If
    If CreateProcessA(vbNullString, sCommandLine, 0, 0, 1, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, vbNullString, uStart, uProcInfo) <> 0 Then
        Call CloseHandle(uProcInfo.hThread)
        m_hProcess = uProcInfo.hProcess
    Else
        Call CloseHandle(m_hReadOutput)
        m_hReadOutput = 0
        Call CloseHandle(m_hReadError)
        m_hReadError = 0
    End If
    Call CloseHandle(hWriteOutput)
    Call CloseHandle(hWriteError)
    '--- success (or failure)
    Run = (m_hProcess <> 0)
    Exit Function
EH:
    PrintError FUNC_NAME
End Function

Public Function AtEndOfError() As Boolean
    Dim lTotal2         As Long

    If m_hReadError <> 0 Then
        If PeekNamedPipe(m_hReadError, ByVal 0, 0, 0, lTotal2, 0) = 0 Then
            Call CloseHandle(m_hReadError)
            m_hReadError = 0
        End If
    End If
    AtEndOfError = (m_hReadError = 0)
End Function

Public Function ReadError(ByVal lSize As Long) As String
    Dim szBuffer        As String
    Dim lRead           As Long

    If m_hReadError <> 0 Then
        szBuffer = String(lSize, 0)
        If ReadFile(m_hReadError, ByVal szBuffer, lSize, lRead, 0) <> 0 Then
            ReadError = Left$(szBuffer, lSize)
        Else
            Call CloseHandle(m_hReadError)
            m_hReadError = 0
        End If
    End If
End Function

Public Function ReadLineError(Optional sTerminator As String) As String
    Do While Not AtEndOfError
        ReadLineError = ReadLineError & ReadError(1)
        If Right$(ReadLineError, 2) = vbCrLf Then
            Exit Function
        ElseIf LenB(sTerminator) <> 0 And Right$(ReadLineError, Len(sTerminator)) = sTerminator Then
            Exit Function
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function

Public Function ReadAllError() As String
    Do While Not AtEndOfError
        ReadAllError = ReadAllError & ReadError(100)
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function

Public Function ReadPendingError() As String
    Dim lTotal          As Long

    Do While Not AtEndOfError
        lTotal = 0
        If PeekNamedPipe(m_hReadError, ByVal 0, 0, 0, lTotal, 0) = 0 Then
            Call CloseHandle(m_hReadError)
            m_hReadError = 0
        End If
        If lTotal > 0 Then
            ReadPendingError = ReadPendingError & ReadError(lTotal)
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function

Public Function AtEndOfOutput() As Boolean
    Dim lTotal2         As Long

    If m_hReadOutput <> 0 Then
        If PeekNamedPipe(m_hReadOutput, ByVal 0, 0, 0, lTotal2, 0) = 0 Then
            Call CloseHandle(m_hReadOutput)
            m_hReadOutput = 0
        End If
    End If
    AtEndOfOutput = (m_hReadOutput = 0)
End Function

Public Function ReadOutput(ByVal lSize As Long) As String
    Dim szBuffer        As String
    Dim lRead           As Long

    If m_hReadOutput <> 0 Then
        szBuffer = String(lSize, 0)
        If ReadFile(m_hReadOutput, ByVal szBuffer, lSize, lRead, 0) <> 0 Then
            ReadOutput = Left$(szBuffer, lSize)
        Else
            Call CloseHandle(m_hReadOutput)
            m_hReadOutput = 0
        End If
    End If
End Function

Public Function ReadLineOutput() As String
    Do While Not AtEndOfOutput
        ReadLineOutput = ReadLineOutput & ReadOutput(1)
        If Right$(ReadLineOutput, 2) = vbCrLf Then
            Exit Function
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function

Public Function ReadAllOutput() As String
    Do While Not AtEndOfOutput
        ReadAllOutput = ReadAllOutput & ReadOutput(100)
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function

Public Function ReadPendingOutput() As String
    Dim lTotal          As Long

    Do While Not AtEndOfOutput
        lTotal = 0
        If PeekNamedPipe(m_hReadOutput, ByVal 0, 0, 0, lTotal, 0) = 0 Then
            Call CloseHandle(m_hReadOutput)
            m_hReadOutput = 0
        End If
        If lTotal > 0 Then
            ReadPendingOutput = ReadPendingOutput & ReadOutput(lTotal)
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Function

Public Function WriteInput(sValue As String) As Boolean
    Dim lWritten        As Long
    DoEvents
    If m_hWriteInput <> 0 Then
        If WriteFile(m_hWriteInput, ByVal sValue, Len(sValue), lWritten, 0) <> 0 Then
            DoEvents
            'Call FlushFileBuffers(m_hWriteInput)
            WriteInput = True
        Else
            WriteInput = False
        End If
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetExitCode() As Long
    If m_hProcess <> 0 Then
        Call GetExitCodeProcess(m_hProcess, GetExitCode)
        If GetExitCode = STATUS_PENDING Then
            If m_hReadOutput <> 0 Then
                Call CloseHandle(m_hReadOutput)
                m_hReadOutput = 0
            End If
            If m_hReadError <> 0 Then
                Call CloseHandle(m_hReadError)
                m_hReadError = 0
            End If
            If m_hWriteInput <> 0 Then
                Call CloseHandle(m_hWriteInput)
                m_hWriteInput = 0
            End If
            Call WaitForSingleObject(m_hProcess, INFINITE)
            Call GetExitCodeProcess(m_hProcess, GetExitCode)
        End If
        Call CloseHandle(m_hProcess)
        m_hProcess = 0
    End If
End Function

Public Function KillProcess() As Boolean
    If Not AtEndOfOutput And Not AtEndOfError Then
        If TerminateProcess(m_hProcess, 0) <> 0 Then
            KillProcess = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    If m_hProcess <> 0 Then
        KillProcess
        Call CloseHandle(m_hProcess)
        m_hProcess = 0
    End If
    If m_hReadOutput <> 0 Then
        Call CloseHandle(m_hReadOutput)
        m_hReadOutput = 0
    End If
    If m_hReadError <> 0 Then
        Call CloseHandle(m_hReadError)
        m_hReadError = 0
    End If
    If m_hWriteInput <> 0 Then
        Call CloseHandle(m_hWriteInput)
        m_hWriteInput = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Visual Basic does not support multi-threading...

Answer (score 0):

While not ideal you can do this without multithreading by using a Timer to poll for child process output.  You can find a UserControl implementing the entire thing at [ShellPipe "Shell with I/O Redirection" control](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?660014-VB6-ShellPipe-quot-Shell-with-I-O-Redirection-quot-control) which isn't perfect but pretty usable code just as it is (full source provided there).

You could also read through that code and adopt the technique in your own programs if you don't want to use that UserControl.

Look at the updated version in post #8 there.